# HTML5 плеер для потокового видео HLS

Tags: html5, потоки-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие существуют кроссбраузерные решения для `m3u8` потока, кроме Video.js и Clappr? Так как первый, время от времени не может подсчитать content-length сегмента, а разработчики второго сами не знают почему в плагине не работает класс `MediaControl`. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

projekktor может подойти, как вариант